# Maintaining user's formatting in Text Area

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, textarea, text-formatting

I am wrting a Rails app. One part of the app takes a user's input from a textarea, sticks that into a database, and then renders it on another page.  How do I make sure that the user's carrige returns and other text formatting are maintained through this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) and [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) methods (you can use them together)